# C++ programming creature game

Tags: c++

I'm making a program in `c++`, more specifically a game, where I have a *creature* class and a *food* class.

They are both randomly placed of a 30x30 2d grid using a random class and a console class. The creatures start off on 5 lives.

Here is where I am stuck.... The creatures lives are suppose to decrement if the food is not within 3 spaces of the creature, in other words to far away for it to eat, and increment if it is however i have the creatures and food randomly generating on screen but dont know the code to say "if food is within 3 spaces increment, else decrement"

*could anyone help?*

Here's the code

```
#include "creature.h"
#include "console.h"
#include "Food.h"
#include "Random.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;


int main()
{


const int BOARD = 30;
int Creat []; 
int FOOD=10;
int CreatureLife=5;

RandomNumber rand;
rand.initialiseSeed();



Console board;

board.gotoXY(00,40);
cout << "How many Creatures do you want to play with?" << endl;
cin >> Creat;

    for (int i = 0; i < Creat; i++)
    {
        Creature();
        board.setColour(board.WHITE, board.BLUE);
        Creature creatp;
        creatp.setpos(BOARD);
        board.gotoXY(creatp.getX(), creatp.getY());
        cout << i;
        int creatX = creatp.getX();
        int creatY = creatp.getY();

        board.gotoXY(40, 10);
                        Creature creatE;
                        creatE.energyDisplay();
                        cout << "Creature " << Creat << " has " << CreatureLife << " Energy " << endl;  


    }



    for (int i = 0; i < FOOD; i++)
    {

        board.setColour(board.BLACK, board.YELLOW);
        Food foodp;
        foodp.setpos(BOARD);
        board.gotoXY(foodp.getX(), foodp.getY());
        cout << 'F';
        int foodX = foodp.getX();
        int foodY = foodp.getY();

    }



    board.gotoXY(00, 32);
        system("pause");
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: post some code that we can use as reference.

Comment: could you explain a bit more what make you stuck?

Comment: I have added my code in the answers

Comment: @fozzy, add it in ur question instead

Answer (score 0):

The minimal one would be: Calculate the offset by 3 from your current creature location (upper left => currentx-3, currenty-3, lower right is currentx+3, currenty+3. Needs some index checking; then scan through the list of positions for food present.

Comment: Sorry as you probably already worked out i'm a novice with programming. Where should i add it and would it be in an if statement?

Comment: Assuming your grid starts at (0,0) and ends at (max-x, max-y) you need to check that:none of the offsets you have are negative (set them to 0) or go beyond your max values (set to max-x or max-y value instead respectively ). The rest is a set of nested for loops from currenty-3 (or adjusted value) to currenty+3 (or adjusted) with the inner loop running he same for the x-values. you can make it faster with some other loop construct and conditionals. All this assumes you have a way of querying what item is at location (x,y).  HTH